# azure cli on osx is failing to authenticate

Tags: macos, azure, azure-storage

I have to download some files **from** azure **to** local, using a Mac.

I have been given this Windows command line:

```
AzCopy /Source:https://XXX.blob.core.windows.net/YYY /SourceKey:TQSxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxpbA== /Dest:C:\myfolder  /Pattern:c /S
```

I have downloaded and installed `azcopy`, but it has a **radically** different syntax, and despite I've been trying for quite some time, I haven't been able to make it work.

What's the correct syntax, given this one?

Looking at some documentation, I've tried:

```
azcopy cp "https://XXX.blob.core.windows.net/YYY/TQSxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxpbA==" "azcopy_dest" --recursive
```

but it doesn't work:

failed to perform copy command due to error:

> cannot start job due to error: cannot list blobs for download. Failed
>   with error ->
>   github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/vendor/github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/azblob.NewResponseError,
>   /go/src/github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/vendor/github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/azblob/zz_generated_response_error.go:28
>
> ===== RESPONSE ERROR (ServiceCode=ResourceNotFound) ===== Description=The specified resource does not exist.

Comment: Got the same error when use [AZcopy 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2ftables%2ftoc.json#authentication-options) on Linux VM with sas token. Not sure why this happens, but you can download a single file with OAuth token, please use login command first if not yet logged in `azcopy cp "https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[path/to/blob]" "/path/to/file.txt" `

Answer (score 0):

From you description it seems you are using AZCopy 10, which mean you do not need to specify key. You either need to generate a SAS token or Login before using azcopy.

1. create a token

`azcopy cp "https://XXX.blob.core.windows.net/YYY?[SAS]" "/path/to/dir" --recursive=true`

2. Login `azcopy login --tenant-id "your tenantid"`

`azcopy cp "https://XXX.blob.core.windows.net/YYY" "/path/to/dir" --recursive=true`

Used Linux, do not have a Mac but should be the same across all platform.

Hope this helps.